# How to use greater than operator with date?

Tags: mysql, date, operators

No idea what is going on here.  Here is the query, right from phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM `la_schedule` WHERE 'start_date' >'2012-11-18';
```

But I consistently get all records in the table returned, including those with start date 2012-11-01.  What gives?

Comment: Is your start_date column of type date or timestamp ?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

you have enlosed `start_date` with single quote causing it to become string, use `backtick` instead

```
SELECT * FROM `la_schedule` WHERE `start_date` > '2012-11-18';
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/117cf/167/0)

Comment: what happens if its timestamp?

Comment: It bears noting that MySQL seems a bit picky about the date format; while either 2019/02/08 21:04:07 or 2019-02-08 21:04:07 produces the expected outcome, 02-08-2019 21:04:07, using the US date format, casts a much wider net.

Answer (score 26):

In your statement, you are comparing a string called **start_date** with the time. 
If **start_date** is a column, it should either be

```
 
  SELECT * FROM `la_schedule` WHERE start_date >'2012-11-18';
```

(no apostrophe)
or

```
SELECT * FROM `la_schedule` WHERE `start_date` >'2012-11-18';
```

(with backticks). 
 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM la_schedule WHERE `start_date` > '2012-11-18';
```

Answer (score 5):

I have tried but above not working after research found below the solution.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where DATE(start_date) > '2011-01-01';
```

[Ref](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datetime/)

Answer (score 4):

Adding this since this was not mentioned.

`` SELECT * FROM `la_schedule` WHERE date(start_date) > date('2012-11-18'); ``

Because that's what actually works for me. Adding date() function on both comparison values.

PS:
As @NikolajHansen has pointed out in the comment, this might not be the ideal solution, since this could run the date function in every row.

Comment: you would then start out by running the date function on all rows in table la_schedule. then comparing it to the right side of the comparison - if its a large dataset - this could give you trouble

Comment: @NikolajHansen. when thinking back again. Yes seems like it might have an optimization issue. I agree. I'll just amend the concern to the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case my column was a datetime it kept giving me all records. What I did is to include time, see below example

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where start_date > '2011-01-01 01:01:01';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing timestamp - you could try following

```
select * from table where columnInTimestamp > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000) - (1*24*60*60*1000))
```

Here UNIX_TIMESTAMP()gives current timestamp where as "1*24*60*60*1000" is the timestamp for 1 day -- With this you can find data just got created in 1 day or 2 days etc.