# In MySQL grab items within start_date and end_date

Tags: php, mysql

I have events listed in my MySQL database.

Events have a start_date (date) and end_date (date) fields.

In my application users can click on a specific day using a calendar.  So, if they click today they are taken to /events?day=2013-08-08 and all events from that day are shown on the page.

This was working great until I started adding multi day events.  Since previously I was just asking MySQL for all events where start_date == the user chose date, I only get events that START on that day, BUT I also want events that may have started before that day but are still going ON that day.

How can I query items like this?  All events that either start on this day, or started earlier but havent yet ended by this day.

Comment: As long as the type of field is DATE, you can compare them using < > and DATE_SUB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448340/sql-greater-than-date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE '2013-08-08' BETWEEN start_end AND end_date
```

where

```
foo BETWEEN bar AND baz
```

is the SQL equivalent of

```
(bar <= foo) AND (foo <= baz)
```

Comment: I believe `OR ('2013-08-08' = start_date OR '2013-08-08' = end_date)` should be added as well as you ask for `BETWEEN` while 'on' is also valid

Comment: no, totally unecessary. `between` is inclusive, e.g. `<=`, not `<`.

Comment: You are right: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0):

```
where start_date>='$inputdate' AND end_date<='$inputdate'
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

If your end date is not yet set for the tasks still going on:

`where '2013-08-08' == start_date or end_date is null`