# How to delete rows which have a field greater than 24 hours

Tags: java, mysql, database, multithreading, prepared-statement

I have a table which contains 2 user names and a date - I need a way of processing the table so that when the date stored is greater than 24 hours / 1 day - then it is removed.

I am thinking that my java application could have a thread that could poll and do this, alternatively - is there a solution that could be crafted on the database side? For example, a stored procedure?

Thanks

Comment: Start by having a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448340/sql-greater-than-date) and [Datetime equal or greater than today in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql)

Comment: Maybe with a trigger: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Mysql [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events.html) to periodically perform an action on the database side.

You can also do it programmatically in java using a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
// execute every 15 seconds
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // execute query to delete the proper data
    }
}, 0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: which would you suggest is the best approach - ideally i think thje database handling it but i would like to know if this is maybe not ideal?

Comment: It depends. If this value should really not be in the db, then the db should handle it. If the role of the program is to clean the database while the database can well contain the data to delete, then the probram should do it. If the database should keep the data to keep track of the past insertions and your programs reading the database should just select the data they need, then nobody should delete anything.

Answer (score 1):

To run stuff periodically in MySql try [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Sample Evnet definition from MySql docs:

```
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
    COMMENT 'Clears out sessions table each hour.'
    DO
      DELETE FROM site_activity.sessions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like:

`db.query("DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, NOW(), yourdate) > 24");`

and run that once a day.

Comment: What's `db`? What's `query`?

Comment: Is that a serious question?

Comment: @DavidXu Yes it is. In java there is no standard data type for database connections which do have a `query` method AFAIK. So you should mention what you are using: What is `db`? What's its type?

Comment: Yes, yes it yes.  If the OP is unfamiliar with Java and JDBC, this is a very misleading answer...the query might be alright, and based on the OP's actually question it might answer 1 of the OP's 4 questions...