# mysqli query by date value

Tags: datetime, mysqli

I have the following mysqli query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY product_price ASC";
```

I would like to only query posts which have a certain date or a date greater than the one set below in `$date`. I have tried the following:

```
$date = '2016-02-28';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE last_updated > $date ORDER BY product_price ASC";
```

Is this the right approach? My dates are currently stored like this:

```
2016-03-01 07:18:17
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain how this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php ?

Comment: It's a duplicate because the way you are running a query is wrong

Comment: Besides, 2016-02-28 = 1986.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `date` > '2012-11-18' ORDER BY `product_price` ASC;
```

if you want to have a go try this [jsfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/325ed/3)

This answer will probably cover your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448340/how-to-use-greater-than-operator-with-date)